# What is the importance of `message Hash` generated from signing using private key

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, web3.py, python, brownie

when we are signing a message using our private key what's the use case of the message hash ?
Take the example from the `eth_accounts` module from python.

```py
>>> msg = "I♥SF"
>>> from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
>>> msghash = encode_defunct(text=msg)
>>> msghash
SignableMessage(version=b'E',
 header=b'thereum Signed Message:\n6',
 body=b'I\xe2\x99\xa5SF')
# If you're curious about the internal fields of SignableMessage, take a look at EIP-191, linked above
>>> key = "0xb25c7db31feed9122727bf0939dc769a96564b2de4c4726d035b36ecf1e5b364"
>>> Account.sign_message(msghash, key)
SignedMessage(messageHash=HexBytes('0x1476abb745d423bf09273f1afd887d951181d25adc66c4834a70491911b7f750'),
 r=104389933075820307925104709181714897380569894203213074526835978196648170704563,
 s=28205917190874851400050446352651915501321657673772411533993420917949420456142,
 v=28,
 signature=HexBytes('0xe6ca9bba58c88611fad66a6ce8f996908195593807c4b38bd528d2cff09d4eb33e5bfbbf4d3e39b1a2fd816a7680c19ebebaf3a141b239934ad43cb33fcec8ce1c'))
```

like here the message hash is `HexBytes('0x1476abb745d423bf09273f1afd887d951181d25adc66c4834a70491911b7f750')`. I mean with the `vrs` or with `signature` & the msg hash we can recover the signer but what's the point of this message hash?